# When the asynchronous operation completed synchronously?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

There is a CompletedSynchronously property in the IAsyncResult interface that returns true if the asynchronous operation is completed synchronously. But in what cases is this not understandable. Is it possible to somehow avoid this? Explain please.

Comment: _"But in what cases is this not understandable"_ -- what do you mean, "not understandable"? I'm not understanding your question. What is it you're worried about? Do you have an actual programming _problem_ you need help solving?

Comment: Why the asynchronous operation completed synchronously?

Comment: _"Why the asynchronous operation completed synchronously?"_ -- because it could. For example, you read from a text reader, but the reader has already buffered the data you need, so it can complete the read immediately instead of waiting on some slower I/O device. Computing platforms are _full_ of various examples of caching, buffering, and other mechanisms designed to improve efficiency, and sometimes they work well enough that something you want done can be done right away instead of waiting for it as might usually be the case.

Answer (score 1):

As [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iasyncresult.completedsynchronously(v=vs.110).aspx) states:

> Use this property to determine if the asynchronous operation completed synchronously. For example, **this property can return true for an asynchronous I/O operation if the I/O request was small**

OP:

> But in what cases is this not understandable. Is it possible to somehow avoid this?

Yes, you should note:

> Most implementers of the IAsyncResult interface will **not** use **this property** and should **return false**. Beginning with the .NET Framework 4.5, a task that is created with the FromAsync method **will not complete if this property is not implemented correctly**. See Application Compatibility in the .NET Framework 4.5.

Comment: What mean "request was small"?

Comment: I have several identical requests. Some are executed synchronously, some asynchronously

Comment: @Mihail _"small"_ refer to Peter's comment above your question